# СДК для трекинга в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Появилась идея сделать что-то связанное с трекингом, пусть даже лица (как те же маски в инстаграме к примеру), просто ради интереса

покопавшись практически ничего не нашел кроме как всяких ар сдк, но не думаю что они мне подходят, ибо мне нужно следить за движениями на камере, а не просто исходя из плоскости что-то размещать на ней в виртуальном пространстве.

Нужно конкретно чтоб юнити понимал, что это моя голова к примеру, и понимал что когда я ее поворачиваю, или же поднимаю

возможно документации какие, исходники похожее на то что я описал, или что-то в таком духе. Пусть даже оно будет максимально костыльным образом сделано, главное чтобы хоть как-то да работало.

Ибо сам я не разбираюсь в этом, но желаю , повторюсь, я нашел только какие-то сдк и вебкам текстуру для юнити, ничего более, и поэтому задаю данный вопрос вам.

Comment: Это называется Дополненная реальность или AR.

Comment: это не ар, далеко не ар, мне нужно управление игрой посредством трекинга лица или рук через камеру, это не ар

Comment: Это часть АР. Ибо АР это и трекинг лица и отрисовка чего-либо.

Answer (score 1):

Гуглится по буквальному прямому запросу "unity face tracking"

и первая же ссылка на документацию:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.xr.arkit-face-tracking.html

так что то, что ты ищешь это "ARKit Face Tracking"

Comment: так что, я гуглю всегда на русском

Comment: @PSENHI на русском в десятки раз меньше нужных материалов. Вообще быть разработчиком без знания англиского тяжеловато. Поэтому надо обязательно уметь гуглить по-английски.